# having a problem with understanding indentation in nested loops

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, indentation

Why is print(j) not showing just 100 here in the code? Why not 10 and 100 as it’s in the list?
here is the code :

````
x = [1, 2]
y = [10, 100]

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(i * j)
        print(i)
    print(j)```

output:

1 
1
100
20
2
200
2
100
````

Comment: Because `print(j)` is not in the scope of the inner loop, it holds only the last value assigned to `j`. You need to shift it right.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough re-population to comment, So Take look on this here 10 and 100:

```
>>> for i in x:
print(i)
for j in y:
    print(j)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print( i * j)

        
1
10
100
2
10
20
100
200
```